# jQuery Filter Data in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table of data on my page and then a couple of buttons that the user can click on. Depending on which button is clicked, it will show/hide rows in the table which match the criteria of the button clicked.

Below you will see my HTML table as well as the switch statement that is triggered when the button is clicked.

My table contains data in the `tr` class with the criteria which are regions. If a user wants to see only results that impact the `EMEA` region, they can click on the `EMEA` button. When they do click `EMEA`, it will hide all table rows where `EMEA` is not found in the `tr` class.

The two statements I am having trouble with are `global` and `multiple`.

If `global` is selected, all 3 regions must be in the class. If `multiple` is selected, at least two of the regions needs to be in the class.

Any thoughts?

```
// Here is my table of data
<table class="res">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <td>Blah</td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="results">
     <tr class="EMEA APAC">
       <td>I Impact Two Regions (Multiple)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="EMEA">
       <td>I Impact One Region (EMEA)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="EMEA APAC AMERICAS">
       <td>I Impact All Regions (Global)</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

...
Buttons on the page trigger the below switch statement
...

// When clicking on the filter button such as "Multiple, Global, or EMEA"    
switch (type) {
    case 'global':
          // If we impact all 3 regions..
          $('.res').find('.results tr').each(function() {
             // If this row doesn't have all 3 regions, we hide it
          });
        break;
    case 'multiple':
         // If we impact any combination of two regions
         $('.res').find('.results tr').each(function() {
             // If this row doesn't have a combination of any two regions, we hide it
         });
        break;
    case 'EMEA':
        // If we impact EMEA
        $('.res').find('.results tr').each(function() {
           // If this row doesn't have only the EMEA region, we hide it
        });
        break;
}
```

Comment: have you considered using [JQuery Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) ?

Comment: I am actually using it on this project. I wasn't sure of how this could be accomplished using the plugin.

Comment: I'd consider adding a new data attribute to assign a "number of regions" value to each table row. `<tr class="EMEA APAC" data-region-count="2">` Then you can use that number to filter for the "multiple" and "global"

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (type) {
     case 'global':
      // If we impact all 3 regions..
      $('.res').find('.results tr').each(function() {
         // If this row doesn't have all 3 regions, we hide it

 //classes is an array of all the classes applied to the element
         var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);

         if(!(classes.indexOf('EMEA')>-1 && classes.indexOf('APAC')>-1 && classes.indexOf('AMERICAS')>-1))
        {
          $(this).hide();
        }

      });
    break;
    case 'multiple':
     // If we impact any combination of two regions
     $('.res').find('.results tr').each(function() {
         // If this row doesn't have a combination of any two regions, we hide it

        var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);

         if(!($.unique(classes).length>1))
        {
          $(this).hide();
        }

     });
    break;
    case 'EMEA':
    // If we impact EMEA
    $('.res').find('.results tr').each(function() {
       // If this row doesn't have only the EMEA region, we hide it

      var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);

         if(!(classes.indexOf('EMEA')>-1))
        {
          $(this).hide();
        }

    });
    break;
}
```